# Cпрогнозировать размер Jpeg-изображения в байтах

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, вопрос следующий. Программно (на Java) сохраняю картинки в формате Jpeg с помощью метода `ImageIO.write()`. Как известно, в таком случае картинка сохраняется в стандартной для Jpeg 24-битной глубине цвета. Размеры картинки в пикселах известны. Как хотя бы примерно спрогнозировать размер изображения в байтах после сохранения?

Как показала практика, формула `(длина в пикс.)*(ширина в пикс)*(3 байта)` верных результатов не дает.

Comment: экстрасенса вызывать?))

Comment: Нет, как я понимаю, нужно узнать степень сжатия Jpeg, которую использует метод ImageIO.write(). "Формулу" (для понимающих она, конечно, смехотворна) написал, чтобы не было ответов типа "перемножить длину на ширину и..."

Comment: если сложно найти формулу, попробуй сам ее вывести, проведи эксперимент =)

Comment: В силу специфики алгоритма JPEG, затруднительно оценить размер картинки заранее. Возможно, есть смысл попробовать как-то конвертировать изображения в памяти до сохранения в файл и в памяти оценивать размер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово. Для крупных изображений вычисляю размер примерно, учитывая степень сжатия Jpeg (выставил вручную 100%). Для тех, что мельче 5 Мб, вычисляю размер "на лету":

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", bos);                
long fileSizeAfter = bos.toByteArray().length;
```

Comment: Можно сделать лучше. Чтобы не расходовать память, можно создать свой OutputStream, который только считает записанные в него байты и никуда не сохраняет. Тогда вы сможете всё посчитать и не расходовать память для хранения результирующего JPEG'а.

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо!